# iTerm 2 vim t_Co=256

Tags: vim

When I use `vim app/controller/test.rb`, opening the file takes 5 seconds. I have checked my `.vimrc` and I found out that if I delete the `set t_Co=256`, file opens quickly, but the code color highlighting doesn't work. How do I solve this problem?

This is my `.vimrc` file: [[link]](https://gist.github.com/lighter/6111051).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
t_Co=256
```

is useless. Instead, configure iTerm to advertise itself as a 256 colors capable terminal by setting its TERM to

```
xterm-256color
```

somewhere in the profile section of its options window.

Comment: I have change iTerm 2 `Report Terminal Type` to `xterm-256color`

Comment: Then you don't need to do anything: vim will correctly set that option by itself.

Comment: If I cancel the `t_Co=256`, the code color will not work.

Comment: @Lighter did you restart iterm2 after changing the report terminal type?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted.

Comment: I've set that option to `xterm-color256` in iTerm2, but both `$ echo $TERM` and `:echo term` within vim return `screen` and `gnome-terminal` respectively. Weird!

Comment: Ahh, it's tmux that caused it. On the plain iTerm2 shell it returns the correct values.